# convert from sparse Matrix to dense matrix without losing dimnames?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Converting a sparse `Matrix` object (from the `Matrix` package) to a plain old base-R dense `matrix` object appears to lose the row/column names.

```r
m <- matrix(0, 3,3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
dimnames(m)
## [[1]]
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Converting **to** a `Matrix` is fine:

```r
dimnames(M <- Matrix::Matrix(m))
## [[1]]
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
## [[2]]
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

But converting back appears to lose the row/column names:

```r
dimnames(as.matrix(M))
## NULL
dimnames(as(M, "matrix"))
## NULL
```

I know I can work around it by storing the dimnames and then attaching them to the new object (see below), but I don't feel like I should have to ... am I missing either a transparent/better way of making the conversion, or a logical reason why dimnames should *not* be preserved when making this conversion??

```r
## workaround/hack
dn <- dimnames(m)
m2 <- as.matrix(M)
dimnames(m2) <- dn
```

To clarify, I want to handle the case where `M` already exists has been defined *but `m` hasn't* (i.e. the old `m[] <-` trick to replace the contents of `m` while leaving its attributes unchanged doesn't seem to work ...)

Comment: Bug is fixed now, in `Matrix` r3418. Next release should include the patch.

Comment: Thank you, Mikael. (notably for the report).  And Matrix 1.4-0 was indeed released to CRAN yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update 1: [bug report](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=61&atid=294&aid=6751)]**
**[Update 2: [patch](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/Matrix/R/diagMatrix.R?r1=3417&r2=3418&pathrev=3418&root=matrix&view=diff&diff_format=h)]**

The loss of `[dD]imnames` here appears to be a bug in `Matrix`, at least in the implementation of the specific subclass of `"Matrix"` in question, namely `"ddiMatrix"` (see `` ?`ddiMatrix-class` ``).

```r
library("Matrix")
M <- Matrix(0, 3L, 3L, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
M
```

```
3 x 3 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"
  A B C
A 0 . .
B . 0 .
C . . 0
```

There is a method for coercing from `"ddiMatrix"` to `"matrix"`, called when you do `as(M, "matrix")`, but it does not preserve `[dD]imnames`, as you observed.

```r
selectMethod("coerce", signature(from = "ddiMatrix", to = "matrix"))
```

```
Method Definition:

function (from, to = "matrix", strict = TRUE) 
base::diag(if (from@diag == "U") as1(from@x) else from@x, nrow = from@Dim[1])
<bytecode: 0x11e7dc068>
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        from        to      
target  "ddiMatrix" "matrix"
defined "ddiMatrix" "matrix"
```

You can work around the bug with an intermediate coercion from `"ddiMatrix"` to `"dgCMatrix"`, which is a more general and more carefully implemented class of sparse numeric matrices (see `` ?`dgCMatrix-class` ``). The coercions from `"ddiMatrix"` to `"dgCMatrix"` to `"matrix"` *do* preserve `[dD]imnames`:

```r
MM <- as(M, "dgCMatrix")
MM
```

```
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  A B C
A . . .
B . . .
C . . .
```

```r
m <- as(MM, "matrix")
m
```

```
  A B C
A 0 0 0
B 0 0 0
C 0 0 0
```

or simply `m <- as(as(M, "dgCMatrix"), "matrix")`.

To be clear, your approach is both faster *and* more transparent. I am presenting this one mainly to expose the fact that the bug affects `"ddiMatrix"` but not all classes of sparse numeric matrices implemented in `Matrix`. If your use case doesn't actually require `"ddiMatrix"`, then you don't necessarily need to worry about preserving `[dD]imnames` yourself.

FWIW, when struggling with `Matrix` coercions, I have found it helpful to:

1. Use `showClass("Matrix")` to remind myself of the inheritance structure of the `"Matrix"` subclasses.
2. Consult `` ?`<classname>-class` `` for human-readable descriptions of the classes reported in (1) and their slots.
3. Use `selectMethod("coerce", signature(from=, to=))` to find the method actually called by `as` (though, as coercions are often implemented in C, the `selectMethod` result can be unhelpful apart from telling me what to search in `Matrix/src`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the difference between "m" and "M" is the object type:

```
m <- matrix(0, 3,3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
M <- Matrix::Matrix(m)

typeof(m)
#> [1] "double"

typeof(M)
#> [1] "S4"
```

I don't know if there's an 'easy' way, but another alternative might be:

```
m <- matrix(0, 3,3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
dimnames(m)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
M <- Matrix::Matrix(m)
m <- as.matrix(M)
dimnames(m) <- M@Dimnames
m
#>   A B C
#> A 0 0 0
#> B 0 0 0
#> C 0 0 0
```

Or maybe:

```
m <- matrix(M, nrow = M@Dim, dimnames = M@Dimnames)
m
#>   A B C
#> A 0 0 0
#> B 0 0 0
#> C 0 0 0
```